# Prohibition Sign after new installation of MAC OS High Sierra on brand new SSD

Tags: high-sierra

I was reactivating my Macbook Pro mid 2010 with 4gb of ram. There was already a ssd hard disk with sierra which worked flawlessly, but however, I wasn't able to upgrade to "high sierra" and since I needed more space, I bought a brand new Samsung 1tb ssd hard drive.

This said, I had to replace the battery (the old was getting bigger) to get the mac going.

Now I've used the internet install to install automatically High Sierra, and after the first reboot I've got that "prohibition sign", rebooting again and the Macbook did finish the install of High Sierra and I was able to login. After rebooting the Mac again, the prohibition sign was there again, after another reboot...it booted normally.

I've downloaded High Sierra through the App Store and did create a usb stick to install it again. Same procedure, prohibition sign shows up, reboot, login. Now I have changed the hdd cable, and it's still the same effect.

I was thinking about downgrading to Sierra, but after the download from apple directly, I only get an installer which likes to install 16,xx mb and I can't create a bootstick with it.

Since the macbook did function very well before, I'm wondering if there's any issue with an 1 tb ssd ?

Is there any startup log to check? I would be glad for any help!

Note: the ssd seems to be perfectly fine, I've tested it with disk utility pre-installed on the macbook.

Thanks,

Jacques